# How to share a textView within java?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to share text which is saved within a textView in an xml page. Below is the code I currently have which shares a set piece of text but i was wondering if it is possible to share a text piece of text along with the text within the textView?

```
    public void share (View view)
        {                       
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "Ive just completed the quiz with the score";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        }
```

Below is the textView within the xml sheet I am trying to share

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

get value from `textView`

```
String str=textResult.getText().toString()
```

pass it

```
 textResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.RateText);
 share(textResult);
```

and

```
 public void share(TextView view){......}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.textResult);
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have entered the above code but when i run the app it crashes when i try to share, any ideas?

Comment: My first guess is that you need some permissions in your manifest. What is the error you are getting in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for (**"...piece of text along with the text within the textView..."**) is:

```
String shareBody = "Ive just completed the quiz with the score "
                          + tv.getText().toString();
```

where `tv` is the `TextView` which you will pass to your share method instead of a `View`,

i.e **Change:**

```
public void share (View view)
```

**to:**

```
public void share (TextView tv)
```

and

`tv` should be obtained by:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
```